# Illustrator - Transform each scale by specific dimensions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, transform

is there any way how to use Transform Each->Scale with specific dimensions instead of percentage (e.g. 2 cm x 1.3 cm)? If I type a specific dimension it just resets the number to the default "100%".

Thanks!

//I meant resizing not scaling, I just reffered to the settings in the Illustrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Illustrator itself can't do it, that's just how it works. From [Adobe Illustrator help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html):

> You cannot enter a specific width for scaling multiple objects. In Illustrator, you can only scale objects in percentage measurements.

However [John Wundes](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/) made this script that you can use to transform with numeric values instead of percentages: https://github.com/johnwun/js4ai/blob/master/setAllTheThings.jsx

> I made this script because I could find no native way to set the width of all selected objects to 100px at once.

Comment: Thank you Luciano, works like a charm with various units of measurement.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, "scale" *means* a "percentage of known measurements".

**Scale** *always* uses percentages. Scale doesn't accept nor does it calculate exact widths and heights of objects.

If you want to resize an object, or multiple objects, by *specific* measurements you need to use the *Width* and *Height* fields on the **Transform Panel** or **Control Bar**. If you are resizing multiple objects, you will probably need to do this one at a time.

Scale is never going to do what you are trying to do unless you manually calculate what percentage you need. i.e. 1.3 is 0.65% of 2, therefore you could enter .65% for the Scale dialog.

Comment: Hi Scott, that is what I eventually did. I didn't really mean scaling as itself but rather resizing, I just reffered to the settings in the Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this way of doing it...
[image: screenshot of contextual menu bar illustrator]

Use the 'start editing similar shapes together' with your object selected - it will edit every similar object at the same time...